# Decrypt Media Files in chunks and play via AVPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, cryptography, swift2, avplayer

I have a `mp4 video file` which i am `encrypting` to save and `decrypting` to play via AVPlayer.  `Using CRYPTOSWIFT Library for encrypting/decrypting`

Its working fine when i am decrypting whole file at once but my file is quite big and taking 100% CPU usage and lot of memory. So, I need to decrypt encrypted file in chunks.
I tried to decrypt file in chunks but its not playing video as AVPlayer is not recognizing decrypted chunk data maybe data is not stored sequentially while encrypting file. I have tried `chacha20, AES, AES.CTR & AES.CBC` protocols to encrypt and decrypt files but to no avail.

```
extension PlayerController: AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate {

   func resourceLoader(resourceLoader: AVAssetResourceLoader, shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource loadingRequest: AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest) -> Bool {
      let request = loadingRequest.request
      guard let path = request.URL?.path where request.URL?.scheme == Constants.customVideoScheme else { return true }
      if let contentRequest = loadingRequest.contentInformationRequest {
         do {
            let fileAttributes = try NSFileManager.defaultManager().attributesOfItemAtPath(path)
            if let fileSizeNumber = fileAttributes[NSFileSize] {
               contentRequest.contentLength = fileSizeNumber.longLongValue
            }
         } catch { }

         if fileHandle == nil {
            fileHandle = NSFileHandle(forReadingAtPath: (request.URL?.path)!)!
         }
         contentRequest.contentType = "video/mp4"
         contentRequest.byteRangeAccessSupported = true
      }

      if let data = decryptData(loadingRequest, path: path), dataRequest = loadingRequest.dataRequest {
         dataRequest.respondWithData(data)
         loadingRequest.finishLoading()
         return true
      }
      return true
   }

   func decryptData(loadingRequest: AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest, path: String) -> NSData? {
      print("Current OFFSET: \(loadingRequest.dataRequest?.currentOffset)")
      print("requested OFFSET: \(loadingRequest.dataRequest?.requestedOffset)")
      print("Current Length: \(loadingRequest.dataRequest?.requestedLength)")
      if loadingRequest.contentInformationRequest != nil {
         var data = fileHandle!.readDataOfLength((loadingRequest.dataRequest?.requestedLength)!)
         fileHandle!.seekToFileOffset(0)
         data = decodeVideoData(data)!
         return data
      } else {
         fileHandle?.seekToFileOffset(UInt64((loadingRequest.dataRequest?.currentOffset)!))
         let data = fileHandle!.readDataOfLength((loadingRequest.dataRequest?.requestedLength)!)
// let data = fileHandle!.readDataOfLength(length!) ** When I use this its not playing video but play fine when try with requestedLength **
         return decodeVideoData(data)
      }
   }
}
```

Decode code to decode nsdata :

```
 func decodeVideoData(data: NSData) -> NSData? {
      if let cha = ChaCha20(key: Constants.Encryption.SecretKey, iv: Constants.Encryption.IvKey) {
         let decrypted: NSData = try! data.decrypt(cha)
         return decrypted
      }
      return nil
   }
```

I need help regarding this issue, Kindly guide me to the right way to achieve this.

Comment: Do you like to play it chunk by chunk? In that case look at  'HTTP live stream'. Do you like to decrypt the whole 'media file' in chunks?  In that case, what is the trouble?

Comment: I have tried to decrypt a chunk at a time but AVPlayer is not playing the video as i thought maybe the encrypted file is not written with data sequentaily ? How can i use http stream to play local file can you elaborate ?

Comment: It doesn't work, because your decodeVideoData initializes decoder with the same key and nonce every time (it starts the 'one time pad' again and again, doesn't matter from which file offset you read the data).  Generally 'on demand' decoding with seek in encoded file is not possible.

Comment: It is working if i am passing `requestedLength` from loadingRequest.

Comment: Ok, maybe i am doing it wrong, Can you elaborate what should i do to get it working ? A small rewrite of a code would be great. Thanks!

Comment: @user3441734 any luck ?

Comment: i can give you an example how to encrypt / decrypt big file in chunks. But start decrypting in general offset in encrypted file is not possible ... the only way to skip the bytes before seek position is to 'fake' decoding the same number of bytes first (you need the same time to do it, as decode the bytes, so it is really not the best approach ... )

Comment: ok waiting for example

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110987/discussion-between-user3441734-and-muhammad-yawar-ali).

Comment: @MuhammadYawarAli have you find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

For in depth and a more complete CommonCrypto wrapper, check out [my CommonCrypto wrapper](https://github.com/Craz1k0ek/CCWrapper). I've extracted bits and pieces for this answer.

First of all, we need to define some functions that will do the encryption/decryption. I'm assuming, for now, you use AES(256) CBC with PKCS#7 padding. Summarising the snippet below: we have an update function, that can be called repeatedly to consume the chunks. There's also a final function that will wrap up any left overs (usually deals with padding).

```swift
import CommonCrypto
import Foundation

enum CryptoError: Error {
    case generic(CCCryptorStatus)
}

func getOutputLength(_ reference: CCCryptorRef?, inputLength: Int, final: Bool) -> Int {
    CCCryptorGetOutputLength(reference, inputLength, final)
}

func update(_ reference: CCCryptorRef?, data: Data) throws -> Data {
    var output = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: getOutputLength(reference, inputLength: data.count, final: false))
    let status = data.withUnsafeBytes { dataPointer -> CCCryptorStatus in
        CCCryptorUpdate(reference, dataPointer.baseAddress, data.count, &output, output.count, nil)
    }
    guard status == kCCSuccess else {
        throw CryptoError.generic(status)
    }
    return Data(output)
}

func final(_ reference: CCCryptorRef?) throws -> Data {
    var output = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: getOutputLength(reference, inputLength: 0, final: true))
    var moved = 0
    let status = CCCryptorFinal(reference, &output, output.count, &moved)
    guard status == kCCSuccess else {
        throw CryptoError.generic(status)
    }
    output.removeSubrange(moved...)
    return Data(output)
}
```

Next up, for the purpose of demonstration, the encryption.

```swift
let key = Data(repeating: 0x0a, count: kCCKeySizeAES256)
let iv = Data(repeating: 0, count: kCCBlockSizeAES128)
let bigFile = (0 ..< 0xffff).map { _ in
    return Data(repeating: UInt8.random(in: 0 ... UInt8.max), count: kCCBlockSizeAES128)
}.reduce(Data(), +)

var encryptor: CCCryptorRef?
CCCryptorCreate(CCOperation(kCCEncrypt), CCAlgorithm(kCCAlgorithmAES), CCOptions(kCCOptionPKCS7Padding), Array(key), key.count, Array(iv), &encryptor)

do {
    let ciphertext = try update(encryptor, data: bigFile) + final(encryptor)
    print(ciphertext)    // 1048576 bytes
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

That appears to me as quite a large file. Now decrypting, would be done in a similar fashion.

```swift
var decryptor: CCCryptorRef?
CCCryptorCreate(CCOperation(kCCDecrypt), CCAlgorithm(kCCAlgorithmAES), CCOptions(kCCOptionPKCS7Padding), Array(key), key.count, Array(iv), &decryptor)

do {
    var plaintext = Data()
    for i in 0 ..< 0xffff {
        plaintext += try update(decryptor, data: ciphertext[i * kCCBlockSizeAES128 ..< i * kCCBlockSizeAES128 + kCCBlockSizeAES128])
    }
    plaintext += try final(decryptor)
    
    print(plaintext == bigFile, plaintext)    // true 1048560 bytes
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

The encryptor can be altered for different modes and should also be released once it's done, and I'm not too sure how arbitrary output on the `update` function will behave, but this should be enough to give you an idea of how it can be done using `CommonCrypto`.