# Streaming segmented data with decryption in iOS

Tags: ios, streaming, avplayer

I am creating an application in which i have a requirement to download encrypted Mpeg segment and play the video in player after decryption using a key downloaded from server. I don't know from where to start. I got some help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37014686/decrypt-media-files-in-chunks-and-play-via-avplayer) and working on it, Till time if anyone have ever build or created such feature then please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to do this on an iOS device if you need DRM level protection is to use Apples FairPlay DRM solution.

There is documentation, SDK and a sample app available if you have an apple developer id: https://developer.apple.com/streaming/fps/

Note, however, to actually deploy it you have to be a 'licensed content owner' and I think this is largely aimed at larger operators and content owners so it would be important to check if you fall into their definition of this first:

> Request Deployment Package
>
> If you're a licensed content owner ready to deploy your implementation of FairPlay Streaming to a production environment, request the FPS Deployment Package. Please note that you must be the Team Agent of a development team that is a licensed content owner. The FPS Deployment Package is not available to third parties acting on behalf of licensed content owners.

If you can live with a lower level of protection then AES encrypted HLS may be enough for you - the actual video encryption is pretty much the same as with DRM, but the key itself is not encrypted.

You can use ffmpeg and openssl to create an AES encrypted HLS stream - the ffmpeg documentation (http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Options-34) includes this example script:

```js
#!/bin/sh
BASE_URL=${1:-'.'}
openssl rand 16 > file.key
echo $BASE_URL/file.key > file.keyinfo
echo file.key >> file.keyinfo
echo $(openssl rand -hex 16) >> file.keyinfo
ffmpeg -f lavfi -re -i testsrc -c:v h264 -hls_flags delete_segments \
  -hls_key_info_file file.keyinfo out.m3u8
```